# Proof for Reality of Quadratic Forms for Hermitian Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

The Wikipedia article for Hermitian matrices has the following for a Hermitian matrix A (they do not define $V$)

> $\forall v \in V,\langle v,Av\rangle \in \mathbb{R}$

I know that if v is an eigenvector of A, the proof is pretty simple, since a Hermitian's eigenvalues are real we have

> $Av = v\lambda \xrightarrow{}v^\dagger Av = v^\dagger \lambda v = \lambda v^\dagger v = \lambda |v|^2 \in \mathbb{R}$

How can I generalize this proof for all vectors v?

Comment: By the spectral theorem, any $v$ can be written as a linear combination of orthogonal eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: A number $x$ is real if $x = \overline{x}$. Hermitian matrices satisfy $\langle v, Hw \rangle = \langle Hv, w \rangle$. Now use the definition of an inner product.

Comment: Wouldn't that just get you $\langle v, Hw \rangle = v^\dagger H w = \langle H v, w \rangle = (Hv)^\dagger w = v^\dagger H w$ ?

Answer (score 4):

Elaborating on Joppy's comment:

Because $A$ is Hermitian, $$\langle v, Av \rangle = \langle Av, v\rangle$$

Because the inner product is [conjugate symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition), we have
$$\overline{\langle v, Av\rangle} = \langle Av, v \rangle.$$

Since $\langle v, Av \rangle$ equals its conjugate, it must be real.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Your link goes to a Boston Symphony Recording. Did you mean to put that?

Comment: @johnsmith sorry about that, fixed

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix#Reality_of_quadratic_forms say that v is real. Could you confirm that this is a mistake? It also asserts that the property is not only necessary but also sufficient. Does your argument prove the double implication?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the eigenvalues of A are nondegenerate, we may diagonalize A according to the form

$$ A = P^* Q P $$

Where $*$ denotes transpose conjugation. But now take the transpose conjugate of both sides of this equation and observe it is invariant, (since by assumption on A the matrix Q is a diagonal matrix of purely real eigenvalues, $Q^* = Q$). Explicitly,
$$ A^* = P^* Q^* P^{**} = P^* Q P = A$$ thus A is hermitian.

Another, possibly more rigorous way to think about this is to consider the skew-hermitian matrix $A - A^*$, and show that it is zero. Indeed, if it has a nonzero element, then it must have a nontrivial eigenspace (since it is skew-hermitian), and so there is some vector $|\>w>$ for which
$$ <w \>|A - A^*| \>w>  \>\>=\> w<w\>|\>w> \>\>\neq 0$$

but this contradicts the assumption on A, since $<w\>| A^* |\> w> = (<w\>| A |\> w>)^* = <w\>| A |\> w> $